# How to use for loop along with if inside lambda python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, lambda

I have a dataframe **df** that has a column **tags** . Each element of the column **tags** is a **list of dictionary** and looks like this:

```json
[
    {
        "id": "leena123",
        "name": "LeenaShaw",
        "slug": null,
        "type": "UserTag",
        "endIndex": 0,
        "startIndex": 0
    },
    {
        "id": "1234",
        "name": "abc ltd.",
        "slug": "5678",
        "type": "StockTag",
        "endIndex": 0,
        "startIndex": 0
    }
]
```

The list can have any number of elements.

Sample dataset:

```
 0  some_data  [{'id': 'leena123', 'name': 'leenaShaw', 'slug': None, 'type...
 1  some data  [{'id': '6', 'name': 'new', 'slug': None, 'type...
```

I want to create a list of all the **id**s from the **tags** column where the **type** is **UserTag**

sample output:
`['leena123', 'saily639,...]`

I am trying with this :
 `list(df['tags'].apply(lambda x: d['name'] if any(d['type'] == 'UserTag' for d in x)))`

but it doesn't work. Kindly help pn this.

Comment: Please share a sample of your dataframe with expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`List Comprehension`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists_comprehension.asp) with `df.apply`:

```
df['id'] = df.tags.apply(lambda x: [i['id'] for i in x if i.get('type') == 'UserTag'])
```

Create a `list` from `id` column:

```
import itertools

l = df['id'].values.tolist()
output_id_list = list(itertools.chain(*l))
```

If you want to drop `id` column from `df`, do:

```
df.drop('id', inplace=True)
```

Comment: This is creating a new column with the usertags. I want a list with the user tags as follows ```['leena123', 'saily639,...] ```

Comment: You want to replace existing `tags` column?

Comment: No. I do not add the a new column or replace the existing tags. I want to have a list of the ```id``` where ```type``` is ```userTag```.

Comment: @dipanjana Please check my updated answer.